# Projective norm for Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The projective norm of tensors from (algebraic) tensor product of Banach spaces $X,Y$ is defined as
$$\|t\|_\wedge = \inf\left\{ \sum\limits_{j=1}^N \|x_j\|\|y_j\| \, : \, t=\sum\limits_{j=1}^N x_j\otimes y_j\right\}.$$

In one place I found slightly different definition:
$$\|t\|_\wedge '=\inf\left\{\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^N \|x_j\|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^N \|y_j\|^2\right)^{1/2} \, : \, t=\sum\limits_{j=1}^N x_j\otimes y_j\right\}.$$

Are they indeed equal? It is easy to see one inequality, but why we have the opposite one?

Comment: I don't think that the opposite inequality holds.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, I though similarly, but on the other hand the projective norm is known to be the largest one which possesses some additional features, so I started to think that maybe it is indeed the case and these two norms are the same. My idea for searching for possible proof of this was to rewrite is some way the tensor product (using e.g. the fact that we can "change scalars between factors" and e.g. divide one side by some factor (that include e.g. its norm) and multiply the second one by the same factor) in order to get the second representation, but it seems that it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two norms are indeed equal. On the one hand, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lVert x_j\rVert \lVert y_j\rVert \leqslant \Biggl(\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lVert x_j\rVert^2\Biggr)^{1/2} \Biggl(\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lVert y_j\rVert^2\Biggr)^{1/2}$$
which yields $\lVert t\rVert_{\wedge} \leqslant \lVert t\rVert'_{\wedge}$. I suppose that's the inequality you saw.

On the other hand, consider when we have equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. A particular case where we have equality is when $\lVert x_j\rVert = \lVert y_j\rVert$ for $1 \leqslant j \leqslant N$.

We can always achieve that by moving a scalar factor from $x_j$ to $y_j$, unless one of $x_j$ and $y_j$ is zero. But excluding all representations
$$t = \sum_{j = 1}^{N} x_j \otimes y_j \tag{1}$$
where at least one of the $x_j$ or $y_j$ is zero doesn't change either norm. For the first, including or excluding such terms doesn't change $\sum \lVert x_j\rVert \lVert y_j\rVert$ at all, for the second, the value for the sum without zero factors is smaller (or equal, if $x_j$ and $y_j$ are both zero for such terms), so the terms we exclude can't make the infimum, i.e. $\lVert t\rVert'_{\wedge}$ smaller.

Thus for a representation $(1)$ where no $x_j$ or $y_j$ vanishes, define
$$c_j = \sqrt{\frac{\lVert x_j\rVert}{\lVert y_j\rVert}}$$
and $x_j' = c_j^{-1}\cdot x_j$, $y_j' = c_j \cdot y_j$. Then we have
$$t = \sum_{j = 1}^{N} x_j' \otimes y_j'$$
and
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lVert x_j\rVert \lVert y_j\rVert = \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lVert x_j'\rVert \lVert y_j'\rVert = \Biggl(\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lVert x_j'\rVert^2\Biggr)^{1/2} \Biggl(\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lVert y_j'\rVert^2\Biggr)^{1/2}$$
which shows
$$\lVert t\rVert'_{\wedge} \leqslant \lVert t\rVert_{\wedge}\,.$$